# Laravel 5.1 | VueJs request randomly returns a login request

Tags: laravel, http-post, laravel-5.1, vue.js

Im working on a project using vuejs and laravel 5.1 but i have a major problem. When i add data to the database using this code through Vuejs it randomly returns with a get request to the login page and doesn't enter the data.

```
    this.$http.post('createAccount', this.account, function (data) {
        //disable the loader
        $('#loader').removeClass('active');

        //show the success message with the new user url
        var url = 'account=' + data;
        var astr ="<a href='" + url + "'>" + " Success! View The Account By Clicking Here " + "</a>";

        //Display sweet alert notification
        global.displaySuccess('User Created', astr);

        alert(astr);

        }).error(function(data, status, request) {
            global.displayError(status, 'Something went wrong!',
            'Please make sure that all the fields are filled out!');
    });
```

The above code works just fine about 3 times before it sends a request to go back to the login page as shown below.

[image: Login request as well as create account request]

And also when this happens sweet alert returns an extra 2 characters at the beginning of where the link should be. (Below Image)

[image: Look at red circle]

If you reference back to the code, note the `alert(astr)`, this is just to see whats being returned by the data. Every time the login request is randomly added this alerts the HTML code for the login page.

[image]

Lastly just incase anyone is curious this is route that its being posted to along with the code that its accessing in the controller.

```
//routes.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'profitloss', 'middleware' => 'perm'], function(){
    post('createAccount', 'AccountController@create');
});

//AccountController@create

 public function create(Request $request)
{

    $account = new Account();

    $account->account_username      = $request->input('account_username');
    $account->account_password      = $request->input('account_password');
    $account->email_address         = $request->input('email_address');
    $account->email_password        = $request->input('email_password');
    $account->notes                 = $request->input('notes');
    $account->gender                = $request->input('gender');
    $account->display_name          = $request->input('display_name');
    $account->first_name            = $request->input('first_name');
    $account->last_name             = $request->input('last_name');

    $account->save();

    //return the id of that account.
    return $account->id;

}
```

NOTE: I've had to disable CSRF because for some reason it keeps failing validation half the time and working the other half, However I don't think that this has anything to do with it.

Any help or information from anyone who has had a similar error to this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Im not sure what file to look at in storage

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say what does the `log` say?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ah this is the most recent log `Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: I didnt know those were a thing i always though that it displays any error straight to the page, Could this be the reason for random logouts?

Comment: Tough to say, but I would start here trying to resolve this foreign key constraint issue as a starting place.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that could be a song!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is this happening, its annoying because now its not replicating the error but im sure randomly when i've further developed the application it wont hesitate to show up unexpectedly